# Segmentation Fault when assigning value to a pointer after `realloc`

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, realloc

I am very new to C (started 4 days ago, do have a background in Python and Java). I tried to create a dynamic array (python list) to solve [advent of code day 4](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/4) part 2. The `own` list and `win` list works normally, I don't understand why the `cardInstancesCount` just refused to take in a value.

Valgrind output

```bash
==1444== Invalid write of size 4
==1444==    at 0x1097FD: main (part2.c:91)
==1444==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

---

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_a_num_char(char *p_char) { return (*p_char >= '0' && *p_char <= '9'); }

int extract_int(char **p_start) {
    char *p_end = *p_start;
    while (is_a_num_char(p_end)) p_end++;
    size_t length = p_end - *p_start;
    char tmp[length + 1];
    tmp[length] = '\0';
    memcpy(tmp, *p_start, length);
    *p_start = p_end;
    return (int)strtol(tmp, (char **)NULL, 10);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int res = 0;
    char buffer[500];
    int tmpNum;
    int cardQuantity = 0;
    int *cardInstancesCount = NULL;

    for (int cardIdx = 0; fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file); cardIdx++) {
        int *win = NULL;
        int *own = NULL;
        int winIdx = 0;
        int ownIdx = 0;
        int matchCount = 0;

        char *p_line = buffer;
        // Skip to ':'
        while (*p_line != ':') p_line++;

        // Load list of winning numbers
        for (; *p_line != '|'; p_line++) {
            if (!is_a_num_char(p_line)) {
                continue;
            }
            tmpNum = extract_int(&p_line);
            int *tmp = realloc(win, sizeof(int) * (winIdx + 1));
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", "Memory Allocation Failed");
                return 1;
            }
            win = tmp;
            win[winIdx++] = tmpNum;
        }

        // Load list of own numbers
        for (; *p_line != '\0'; p_line++) {
            if (!is_a_num_char(p_line)) {
                continue;
            }
            tmpNum = extract_int(&p_line);
            int *tmp = realloc(own, sizeof(int) * (ownIdx + 1));
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", "Memory Allocation Failed");
                return 1;
            }
            own = tmp;
            own[ownIdx++] = tmpNum;
        }

        // Check how many matchings
        for (int ownCheckIdx = 0; ownCheckIdx < ownIdx; ownCheckIdx++) {
            for (int winCheckIdx = 0; winCheckIdx < winIdx; winCheckIdx++) {
                if (own[ownCheckIdx] == win[winCheckIdx]) {
                    matchCount++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        free(win);
        free(own);

        if (cardQuantity == cardIdx) {
            printf("%p\n", &cardInstancesCount);
            int *tmp =
                realloc(cardInstancesCount, sizeof(int) * (cardQuantity + 1));
            if (tmp = NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", "Memory Allocation Failed");
                return 1;
            }
            cardInstancesCount = tmp;
            printf("%p\n", &cardInstancesCount);
            cardInstancesCount[cardIdx] = 1; // Line 91
            printf("%s\n", "no");
            printf("%d",*cardInstancesCount);
        }

        // If need to expand cardQuantity
        int newCardQuantity = cardIdx + matchCount + 1;
        if (newCardQuantity > cardQuantity) {
            int *tmp =
                realloc(cardInstancesCount, sizeof(int) * newCardQuantity);
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", "Memory Allocation Failed");
                return 1;
            } else {
                cardInstancesCount = tmp;
            }

            // Initialise all 1 for new card discovery
            for (int i = cardQuantity; i < newCardQuantity; i++) {
                cardInstancesCount[i] = 1;
            }
            cardQuantity = newCardQuantity;

            // Add current instance to the cards
            for (int i = cardIdx + 1; i < newCardQuantity; i++) {
                cardInstancesCount[i] += cardInstancesCount[cardIdx];
            }
            // Set newCardQuantity
            cardQuantity = newCardQuantity;
        }
        // If no cardQuantity expansion.
        else {
            for (int i = cardIdx + 1; i < newCardQuantity; i++) {
                cardInstancesCount[i] += cardInstancesCount[cardIdx];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cardQuantity; i++) {
        printf("%d", cardInstancesCount[i]);
    }
    free(cardInstancesCount);
    printf("Res: %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

The code that works for part 1

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_a_num_char(char *p_char) { return (*p_char >= '0' && *p_char <= '9'); }

int extract_int(char **p_start) {
    char *p_end = *p_start;
    while (is_a_num_char(p_end)) p_end++;
    size_t length = p_end - *p_start;
    char tmp[length + 1];
    tmp[length] = '\0';
    memcpy(tmp, *p_start, length);
    *p_start = p_end;
    return (int)strtol(tmp, (char **)NULL, 10);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int res = 0;
    char buffer[500];
    int tmpNum;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)) {
        int *win = NULL;
        int *own = NULL;
        int winIdx = 0;
        int ownIdx = 0;
        int matchCount = 0;

        char *p_line = buffer;
        while (*p_line != ':') p_line++;
        for (; *p_line != '|'; p_line++) {
            if (!is_a_num_char(p_line)) {
                continue;
            }
            tmpNum = extract_int(&p_line);
            int *tmp = realloc(win, sizeof(int) * (winIdx + 1));
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", "Memory Allocation Failed");
                return 1;
            }
            win = tmp;
            win[winIdx++] = tmpNum;
        }
        for (; *p_line != '\0'; p_line++) {
            if (!is_a_num_char(p_line)) {
                continue;
            }
            tmpNum = extract_int(&p_line);
            int *tmp = realloc(own, sizeof(int) * (ownIdx + 1));
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", "Memory Allocation Failed");
                return 1;
            }
            own = tmp;
            own[ownIdx++] = tmpNum;
        }
        for (int ownCheckIdx = 0; ownCheckIdx < ownIdx; ownCheckIdx++) {
            for (int winCheckIdx = 0; winCheckIdx < winIdx; winCheckIdx++) {
                if (own[ownCheckIdx] == win[winCheckIdx]) {
                    matchCount++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (matchCount) {
            res += (int)pow(2, matchCount - 1);
        }
        free(win);
        free(own);
    }
    printf("Res: %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

I try valgrind, try printing out stuff, try using malloc instead of null to assign the first memory address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    realloc(cardInstancesCount, sizeof(int) * (cardQuantity + 1));
if (tmp = NULL) {
```

Line 84. I didn't compare it. Just setting the pointer to `NULL`.